# object snaps to absolute zero when switching between axis during translation - help!

Tags: snapping

When we are translating an object using the middle mouse button - we can move it in a specific direction (x,y,z) but then when we redirect it to a different axis using middle mouse, the object snaps back to absolute zero. It will travel in the desired axis - but starts from absolute zero as opposed to where we currently are. Any clue why this happens?

Comment: Please add more information how and what are you translating. 
By default transformation in Blender is done with keyboard or Left click if using transform widget.

Comment: Use 3 subsequent translations, one for each axis. This behaviour is intended.